# Using a .pdf file as a page in wordpress

Tags: images, url-rewriting, urls, pdf

I'd like to create a link on my wordpress site to a .pdf that I have already created.  Ideally create mywebsite.com/filename.pdf or mywebsite.com/foldername/filename.pdf

I do not need a link or a post or any interaction with the site as it is, I just want to upload a .pdf to my domain and have a url to send out.

Right now I can upload the file and get a url of, mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/filename.pdf.

I've tried to make a new file folder and put the .pdf in it, but the link doesn't work.

As you can tell I am very novice with websites.

Answer (score 1):

just upload it through ftp or your domain hosting panel to your public_html (www) directory.  It will be there as a link to www.example.com/myfile.pdf.

The case may be that if you have wordpress and installed any security plugins you'll have to allow the exception within that plugin as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Placing the file in the root folder worked fine. I had tried to put the file in a new folder that I created in the root. I could never get the path to work. Skipping the folder works great.

Comment: great news.  could you Mark as answered?  (check mark to left of answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file to the media library and then get the link from there. At that point, you can drop the link into the WordPress menu system or anywhere else you need.